# Chebyshev Inequality, possible range of 90th percentile of a 100-vector with rms(x)=1

Tags: linear-algebra, standard-deviation

My lecture notes states the Chebyshev inequality as follows:

> If k is the number of entries of x that satisfy $|x_i − avg(x)| \ge a$,
>   then $k/n \le {(std(x)/a)}^2$.

x is a 100-vector with **rms**(x) = 1.
Let $q_{90}$ be the 90th percentile of the absolute values of the entries of the vector x. How big and how small can $q_{90}$ be?

First, I obtain possible range of values of **avg**(x) from the equality $${rms(x)}^2 = {avg(x)}^2 + {std(x)}^2$$
I get ${avg(x)}^2 = {rms(x)}^2 - {std(x)}^2 \le {rms(x)}^2 = 1$ $\Rightarrow |avg(x)| \le 1$.
Similarly, ${std(x)}^2 = {rms(x)}^2 - {avg(x)}^2 \le {rms(x)}^2 = 1$.

Since $q_{90}$ is the the 90th percentile, there are k=10 values that with $|x_i − avg(x)|\ge a$. Therefore, $1/10 \le {(std(x)/a)}^2 \le 1/a$ $\Rightarrow a \le {\sqrt 10}$.

I feel that possible $q_{90}$ should fall in the range between $min\{avg(x)\}-max\{a\} = -1-{\sqrt 10}$ and $max\{avg(x)\}+max\{a\} = 1+ {\sqrt 10}$, but I am not sure how to justify it.

Is this even correct?
Can anyone point me in the right direction? I would appreciate any help!